# How to build a for-loop to loop through animal IDs?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have GPS data for multiple animals. I need to calculate step-lengths for each individual and then compare average step-length between day and night. The code below does this for one individual, but I need to loop through each individual by their ID.

A little more background - I am doing this because I am unsure if the time column of a data set I am working with has been converted to local time, so I am comparing step-lengths between day and night with the idea that this particular species should be less active during the day. If not, then the times may be wrong. Any help is appreciated!

```
structure(list(`(Id)` = c("151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", 
"151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", 
"151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", 
"151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", 
"151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", 
"151_230_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", 
"151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", 
"151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", 
"151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", 
"151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", 
"151_259_25_2", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", 
"151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", 
"151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", 
"151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", 
"151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", 
"151_259_45_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", 
"151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", 
"151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", 
"151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", 
"151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", 
"151_290_25_1", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", 
"151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", 
"151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", 
"151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", 
"151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", 
"151_290_75_2"), Date = structure(c(14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 
14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 
14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 
14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 
14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 
13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 
13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 
13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 
13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 
13831, 13831, 13831, 13831, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 
14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 
14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197, 14197), class = "Date"), Time = structure(c(0, 
1800, 3600, 5400, 7200, 9060, 10800, 12600, 14400, 16200, 18000, 
19800, 21600, 23400, 25200, 27000, 28800, 30600, 32400, 34200, 
0, 1860, 3600, 5400, 7200, 9000, 10800, 12600, 14400, 16200, 
18000, 19800, 21600, 23400, 25200, 27000, 28800, 30600, 32400, 
34200, 0, 1800, 3600, 5400, 7200, 9000, 10800, 12600, 14400, 
18060, 19860, 21600, 23400, 25200, 27000, 28800, 30600, 32400, 
34200, 36000, 0, 1800, 3600, 5460, 7200, 9000, 10800, 12600, 
14400, 16200, 18000, 19800, 21600, 23400, 25200, 27000, 28800, 
30660, 32400, 34200, 0, 1800, 3600, 5400, 7200, 9000, 10800, 
12600, 14400, 16200, 18000, 19800, 21600, 23400, 25200, 27000, 
28800, 30600, 32400, 34200), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), 
    Id = c("151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", 
    "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", 
    "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", 
    "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", 
    "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", "151_230_25_2", 
    "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", 
    "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", 
    "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", 
    "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", 
    "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_25_2", 
    "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", 
    "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", 
    "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", 
    "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", 
    "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", "151_259_45_1", 
    "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", 
    "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", 
    "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", 
    "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", 
    "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", "151_290_25_1", 
    "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", 
    "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", 
    "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", 
    "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", 
    "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2", "151_290_75_2"
    ), DateTime = structure(c(1226620800, 1226622600, 1226624400, 
    1226626200, 1226628000, 1226629800, 1226631600, 1226633400, 
    1226635200, 1226637000, 1226638800, 1226640600, 1226642400, 
    1226644200, 1226646000, 1226647800, 1226649600, 1226651400, 
    1226653200, 1226655000, 1226620800, 1226622600, 1226624400, 
    1226626200, 1226628000, 1226629800, 1226631600, 1226633400, 
    1226635200, 1226637000, 1226638800, 1226640600, 1226642400, 
    1226644200, 1226646000, 1226647800, 1226649600, 1226651400, 
    1226653200, 1226655000, 1194998400, 1195000200, 1195002000, 
    1195003800, 1195005600, 1195007400, 1195009200, 1195011000, 
    1195012800, 1195016400, 1195018200, 1195020000, 1195021800, 
    1195023600, 1195025400, 1195027200, 1195029000, 1195030800, 
    1195032600, 1195034400, 1194998400, 1195000200, 1195002000, 
    1195003800, 1195005600, 1195007400, 1195009200, 1195011000, 
    1195012800, 1195014600, 1195016400, 1195018200, 1195020000, 
    1195021800, 1195023600, 1195025400, 1195027200, 1195029000, 
    1195030800, 1195032600, 1226620800, 1226622600, 1226624400, 
    1226626200, 1226628000, 1226629800, 1226631600, 1226633400, 
    1226635200, 1226637000, 1226638800, 1226640600, 1226642400, 
    1226644200, 1226646000, 1226647800, 1226649600, 1226651400, 
    1226653200, 1226655000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), x = c(634284.1, 634309, 634408.2, 634375.1, 634311.2, 
    634284.1, 634280, 634287.1, 634282.3, 634279.5, 634345.9, 
    634467.1, 634642.7, 634778.7, 634777.9, 634914.8, 635110.4, 
    635051.1, 634817.2, 634493.2, 632791.5, 632789, 632779.1, 
    632779.2, 632783.7, 632784.7, 632945.4, 632873.2, 632881.8, 
    632914.5, 632902.8, 632880.3, 633005.9, 633126.4, 633178.4, 
    633229.4, 633235.5, 633167.2, 632827.3, 632792.4, 636092.752445996, 
    636085.71870334, 636085.960986795, 636080.209776018, 636067.492673929, 
    636070.703147982, 636067.727121061, 636072.25358048, 636067.733635585, 
    636022.254595604, 636049.378154663, 636052.774163599, 636044.281856078, 
    636020.825814475, 636017.501109539, 635998.576789699, 635984.944547542, 
    635995.97293996, 635994.65604081, 635997.441594901, 634117.793160993, 
    634123.560619043, 634126.79519071, 634139.270126081, 634123.493214937, 
    634129.086702961, 634120.172806562, 634103.476705276, 634114.211880121, 
    634122.412333279, 634147.110097123, 634153.311725244, 634149.622657568, 
    634145.54023752, 634157.538900614, 634176.936148175, 634039.024413502, 
    633994.511113991, 633927.544166519, 633955.807482225, 635746.9, 
    635766.5, 635747, 635748.1, 635750.8, 635749.8, 635665.6, 
    635583.2, 635601.3, 635607.8, 635603.5, 635617.4, 635654.3, 
    635610, 635601.7, 635590.9, 635588.4, 635572.7, 635575.4, 
    635556), y = c(3037674, 3037675, 3037625, 3037597, 3037676, 
    3037666, 3037666, 3037674, 3037666, 3037676, 3037676, 3037662, 
    3037554, 3037480, 3037487, 3037459, 3037446, 3037371, 3037266, 
    3037267, 3038537, 3038509, 3038499, 3038500, 3038504, 3038507, 
    3038609, 3038571, 3038578, 3038605, 3038596, 3038451, 3038321, 
    3038177, 3038169, 3038025, 3037925, 3037819, 3037734, 3037244, 
    3041712.62393865, 3041705.37714781, 3041680.88214683, 3041712.0858203, 
    3041710.34914796, 3041725.55318648, 3041711.4819015, 3041714.05836591, 
    3041708.22447917, 3041671.49952197, 3041727.53247622, 3041733.14336357, 
    3041731.78600236, 3041728.13525523, 3041728.56372061, 3041705.63993685, 
    3041691.98229541, 3041650.88737444, 3041640.44657043, 3041649.43003949, 
    3038454.51463208, 3038449.49203901, 3038450.14785299, 3038461.70743224, 
    3038450.23364733, 3038446.66060605, 3038450.19736362, 3038461.33845936, 
    3038488.30205007, 3038469.55604232, 3038439.77760359, 3038442.9588028, 
    3038435.96038282, 3038440.53603018, 3038445.03260561, 3038458.93924427, 
    3038432.65800031, 3038466.03173824, 3038456.74725178, 3038450.68481899, 
    3037382, 3037380, 3037439, 3037444, 3037441, 3037438, 3037436, 
    3037453, 3037497, 3037513, 3037512, 3037501, 3037198, 3037083, 
    3037073, 3037083, 3037099, 3037123, 3037101, 3037126)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), groups = structure(list(
    `(Id)` = c("151_230_25_2", "151_259_25_2", "151_259_45_1", 
    "151_290_25_1", "151_290_75_2"), .rows = structure(list(1:20, 
        21:40, 41:60, 61:80, 81:100), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .drop = TRUE))
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(amt)
library(lubridate)
library(maptools)
library(suncalc)
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(Id=as.factor(Id),
         DateTime=as.POSIXct(DateTime, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p",tz='CST6CDT')) %>%
  drop_na(DateTime) %>%
  select(Id,Time, DateTime,x,y) %>%
  filter(Id=='151_259_45_1') %>%
  droplevels()
summary(df2, maxsum=20)

all(complete.cases(df2))

# check for duplicated time stamps
any(duplicated(df2$DateTime))

trk<-make_track(df2, x, y, DateTime, id = Id, crs = 4326, all_cols = T)
trk

trk <- trk %>%
  mutate(sl_ = step_lengths(trk))

summarize_sampling_rate(trk)

trk2<-track_resample(trk, rate=minutes(30))
trk2

stp2<-steps_by_burst(trk2)


stp2 <- stp2 %>%
  mutate(time = t1_-6*60*60,
         time=format(time, "%H:%M:%S"))

stp2 <- stp2 %>%
  mutate(time=format(t1_, "%H:%M:%S"))

stp3 <- stp2 %>%
    mutate(time_period=if_else(time > '06:30:00' & time < '19:30:00', "Day", "Night")) %>%
    group_by(time_period) %>%
    mutate(avg_sl=mean(sl_))

ggplot(stp3, aes(time_period, avg_sl)) + 
        geom_bar(stat='summary')
```

Comment: It tends to be good when your sample code works on your sample data, but your code filters `df` to zero rows. I suggest (1) make sure your `filter(Id==.)` is found in your sample data; and more-so since you want to do this for multiple animals, (2) increase your sample data to include at least one other `Id`.

Comment: Do we need `make_track` and `track_resample` to try data-mangling, or are those just code to help you?

Comment: I revised the sample data to include the filtered individual. I am not sure how to include multiple individuals in the sample data because the data set is so large. I do think we need both ```make_track``` and ```track_resample``` but I may be wrong.

Comment: I understand the data being large, that's a common problem. One technique is to reduce to just the columns you need, which may reduce the size of the `structure(..)` significantly.

Comment: I appreciate your help! I think I have it fixed where the included columns are relevant and there are multiple animals in the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for-loops are not recommended in R as they tend to be slow. The preferred way is to use lists. I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but I think what you need is `split()` and `purrr::map()` or `lapply()`. `split()` will split your data frame into a list of data frames, each containing only one ID. `map()` will then apply a given function to each data frame.

```r
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(DateTime = as.POSIXct(DateTime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p", tz = "CST6CDT")) %>%
  drop_na(DateTime) %>%
  select(Id, Time, DateTime, x, y)

# Your code as a function
anaysis <- function(df) {
  description <- summary(df2, maxsum = 20)
  trk <- make_track(df2, x, y, DateTime, id = Id, crs = 4326, all_cols = T)
  trk <- trk %>%
    mutate(sl_ = step_lengths(trk))
  description2 <- summarize_sampling_rate(trk)
  trk2 <- track_resample(trk, rate = minutes(30))
  stp2 <- steps_by_burst(trk2)
  stp2 <- stp2 %>%
    mutate(
      time = t1_ - 6 * 60 * 60,
      time = format(time, "%H:%M:%S")
    )
  stp2 <- stp2 %>%
    mutate(time = format(t1_, "%H:%M:%S"))
  stp3 <- stp2 %>%
    mutate(time_period = if_else(time > "06:30:00" & time < "19:30:00", "Day", "Night")) %>%
    group_by(time_period) %>%
    mutate(avg_sl = mean(sl_))
  plot <- ggplot(stp3, aes(time_period, avg_sl)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "summary")
  lst(description, trk, description2, trk2, stp2, stp3, plot) # return a named list
}

df2 %>%
  split(df2$Id) %>% # mind the `$`
  purrr::map(anaysis)
```

Comment: Jakub this worked perfectly! However, I am new to lists and am having a hard time figuring out how to call on different elements in the list. For example, how do I call on a certain animal plot to replot? I am really interested in plotting all plots in a grid on the same graph. I posted this question here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77959391/how-to-plot-multiple-plots-from-list?noredirect=1#comment137438138_77959391", but I have had any luck with answers. Any help is appreciated!